# How to Access Relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I know the question title is not very clear but please read the complete question as I need help with this.

I have three tables...

- Offers
- Vehicles
- Trims

The relationships are something like this...

**Offer.php**

```
public function vehicle () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
}
```

**Vehicle.php**

```
public function trims () {
  return $this->hasMany(Trim::class);
}

public function offers () {
  return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
}
```

**Trim.php**

```
public function vehicle () {
  return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
}
```

In the single Offer, I can access `$offer->vehicle` but how can I access the Trims of this fetched vehicle? I tried this `$offer->vehicle->trims`and it's not working. It should work because Trims are related to the Vehicle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this $offer->vehicle->trims it's not working.

What does "not working" mean?
`trims()` will not return a single instance but an iterator you have to iterate over or access in an appropriate way.
Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
$comments = App\Post::find(1)->comments;

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the related models of the instance like.

```
Offers::with('vehicle.trims')->find($id);
```

If you want to go the long way you can try.

```
Offers::with(['vehicle' => function($query){
      $query->with('trims');
})->find($id);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use eager loading query - you can pass in a closure to handle the query for the eager-loaded content:

```
$result = Offer::with(['vehicle' => function($query) {
    $query->with('trims');
}])->get();
```